# PBI - How to group by column name in pie chart along percentage (with values displayed)?

Tags: powerbi, pie-chart, dax, percentage

I'm having trouble with use group by on pie chart - maybe it can be done differently.

I have a simple pie chart with only 2 values: `Name`, and their `values` (grouped by the `Name`).

The `values` are an amount and not a percentage. (The percentage may be displayed as well, but only if the amount will be displayed also).

And I need to somehow (I guess with group by) rename all the `Names` where the percentage ratio in this chart lower than, for example, 10% to a different string, like `Group_with_10per_or_lower`.

Any ideas how this can be done?

---

For example, imagine having `States` and their values of something. `USA = 350`; `Canada = 250`, `Brazil = 200`, `Argentina = 150`, `Chile = 50`. And what you have is a pie chart with these data. But you need to rename all states having 20% or less ratio of this value (Brazil, Argentina, and Chile) as `Other` for example. So you would have the pie chart with USA, Canada, and Other (Brazil + Argentina + Chile) but still have their values displayed in the chart and not their %. It can be both, but not just %.

Comment: Can you post an example? Simple dataset example and expected result.

Comment: Sure. Imagine having “States” and their values of something. USA = 350; Canada = 250, Brazil = 200, Argentina = 150, Chile = 50. And what you have is a pie chart with these data. But you need to rename all states having 20% or less ratio of this value  (Brazil, Argentina and Chile) as “Other” for example. So you would have in the end pie chart with USA, Canada, and Other (Brazil+Argentina+Chile). But still their values displayed in the chart and not their %. It can be both, but not just %.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a table `Table1(state, value)`

Create a measure:

```
Total = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[value]),All(Table1))
```

Create a calculated column:

```
state2 = IF([value]<[total]*0.2,"Other",[state])
```

Use state2 in your visualisation.

[image]